# Angular and Single tags and unnecessary attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have

```
<tag zn="abcd" ></tag>
```

I need get

```
<input type="text" value="{{value}}" ></input>
```

But I get unnecessary attribute 'zn'

```
<input type="text" value="abcd" zn="abcd" ></input>
```

I don't need attribute 'zn'

AND MAIN:

This markup works

```
<tag zn="abcd" ></tag>
```

But it doesn't work

```
<tag zn="abcd" />
```

It must be single tag. I get only first element.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XVAFcVOQb4xKkZovybbK?p=preview)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Calendar</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="dir" >
        <tag zn="abcd" >1 </tag><br>
        <tag zn="bcde" >2 </tag><br>
        <tag zn="cdef" >3 </tag><br>
        <tag zn="" >4 </tag><br>
    </div>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var myapp = angular.module("dir", []);

myapp.directive('tag', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        value: '@zn'
      },
      template: '<input type="text" value="{{value}}" ></input>', 

    };
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to remove the attribute manually:

```
myapp.directive('tag', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      value: '@zn'
    },
    template: '<input type="text" value="{{value}}" ></input>',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.removeAttr('zn');
    }
  };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/0BHfyJiOx6q0rxQF3uCZ?p=preview

Don't use self-closing tags as they might not work as expected. It's up to the browser's parser, not AngularJS, if they render correctly.

Always use `<tag zn="abcd" ></tag>` instead of `<tag zn="abcd" />`.

While `<tag />` is valid in **HTML5** - it means `<tag>` and not `<tag></tag>` like it does in **XHTML**.

Comment: Thanks. But browser replace <input>to </input>. And I thought Browser can replace <tag/> to <input> </input>.

Comment: Input is one of a few elements that are treated differently by browsers: http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html